# A question about notation

Tags: soft-question, notation

Earlier this week, a friend asked me what the most complicated equation I could think of was that was equal to $1$. The answer I gave was this:

Let $G_n$ denote the n$th$ number in the grandi series, ($1-1+1-1+1\cdots$). I am doing this assuming that that $\lim_{n \to \infty}G_n = \frac{1}{2}$, which can be achieved through a variety of methods, however this series is not actually convergent. Now let's take that $G_n$ and multiply it by $2$. We'll call this $F_n$. In other words, $F_n := 2(G_n)$. Now let's put this in the Grandi series, just instead of ones, we have $F_n$. Now our formula is $F_n-F_n+F_n-F_n\cdots$, which of course is equal to $\frac{1}{2}$. We would keep going in this fashion an infinite number of times, where each iteration is a reformulation of the Grandi series with a different function. Then, finally, we would multiply the whole thing by $2$. Unless I'm incorrect, this is all equal to $1$.

My question is this: How would you notate the thing I just described? The way I did it was $2(\lim_{n \to \infty}\lim_{x \to \infty}(G_{n,x}))$ where $x$ is the number of times the pattern above is being iterated, but I would like to know if there exists already a notation of the thing I described. Good luck and thanks in advance!

Comment: The limit of $G_n$ in a modern sense (i. e. as limit of the sequence of partial sums) is *not* $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: It is not a well known fact that $\lim_{n \to \infty}G_n = \frac{1}{2}$.  The Cesàro sum may be $\frac{1}{2}$, but that is not the limit of the partial sums, but the limit of the average of the partial sums.

Comment: @Keba, I understand how it wouldn't if you handled it as partial sums, but if you looked at the thing as a whole with no parentheses or anything, wouldn't it be $\frac{1}{2}$? I have seen multiple proofs of this, and it seems to be widely accepted.

Comment: Asking for the "most complex expression" is like asking for the largest natural number. Except less well-defined. Also, the Grandi series certainly does not converge in the usual sense of convergence. On the other hand, you may wish to read about [up-arrow notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth's_up-arrow_notation), which stacks exponentation in way that seems analogous to the recursive notation you are attempting to establish. I'm not suggesting that it's directly relevant, but it may give you a few ideas.

Comment: Well, give me a concept of convergence first, ie. somehow define what you mean by $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} G_n$. And state that concept, as most people won‘t have the same concept in mind. Then of course, depending on your new concept, the series might converge to $\frac{1}{2}$ and maybe (also depending on your concept of course) the other series might as well.

Comment: You're right, just looked it up, I'll edit it.

Comment: Just edited it, does it look like this is correct? I also took away the part about the most complex equation, as asking that I realize now was kind of stupid, as the question is too subjective.

Comment: Can anyone please explain to me why this got down voted in its current form?

Comment: @recursiverecursion If  $Fn:=2(Gn)$, then why would $Fn−Fn+Fn−Fn⋯ = 1/2$ ? Wouldn't $Fn−Fn+Fn−Fn⋯ = 1$ ?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something simple representing the "order" or degree to which you are referring.  For example, instead of saying that $F_n := 2 G_n$, why not say $G_{n}^{(2)} = 2 G_n$.  Now you can easily represent $G_n^{(5007)}$ and you don't need to cycle through letters ;)

Comment: But $G_n^{(5007)} = \frac{5007}{2} \neq 1$ (if $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} G_n = \frac{1}{2}$), or do I miss sth.?

Comment: This looks better that what I came up with :)

Comment: Right @Keba, I see what you mean, but he is both multiplying a series by 2 and applying a function to it.  So $G_n^{(5007)}$ would represent the $5006^{th}$ time you let $F_n = G_n^{i+1} = 2G_n^{i}$, then wrote $F_n - F_n + F_n - ...$.  Maybe this is a bit sloppy :P

Comment: Ah, you meant $G_n^{(m)} := 2G_n^{(m-1)}$, okay. :)

Answer (score 0):

I‘d go with $e^{2 \pi i} = 1$.

I believe this is at least more complicated than taking two limites. But of course the question which one is more complicate is very subjective.